# Disable mouse and key events in Div

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple `Html` elements inside a `div`. Is there any way to disable mouse and key events for that Div(Not for individual elements)? The elements  are auto generated and are inside multiple spans. Hence i just want to disable the whole div so that nothing can be changed but `readonly`.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak As i mentioned above the elements are auto generated. I can just have the id of the `div` nothing more.

Comment: But can't you show the prototype of the elements that you are generating?

Comment: what about [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) jquery function?

Answer (score 8):

Try with **.unbind()** like

```
$('#my_div_id').unbind();
```

it will remove all the events that will attached to that div.See this [**UNBIND**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

You can use .die also like

```
$('#my_div_id').die();
```

Answer (score 7):

As per jQuery docs, unbind method removes a previously-attached event handler from the elements. My understanding is that you just want to prevent the default browser events from being triggered, instead of removing previously attached events.

There is a simple CSS solution for it, which doesn't work on IE10 and below:

```
#yourDiv {pointer-events:none;}
```

A solution using jQuery would be adding an event to your div, and then preventing default behavior from happening on events of your choice:

```
$('#yourDiv').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
});
```

Click events should also work for keyboard access to check boxes and radio buttons, but in case you need, for example, prevent text typing on an input field, just add keyboard events to the list:

```
$('#yourDiv').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
});
$('#yourDiv').keypress(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I am just posting this answer because it might help other people looking for similar functionality, but I believe there are better ways of doing this on your case. You could run a function to set your elements to disabled `$('#yourDiv input').prop("disabled", true);` after loading. Hard to tell without knowing your html.

Comment: #yourDiv {pointer-events:none;} is not working up through IE11

Comment: Nice catch @JackFairfield. I have updated the answer based on this table - http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: This doesn't disable keyboard events.  If you want to disable keyboard events, it's because you already have listeners attached.  If you apply this listener after the ones already attached, the other ones will still run, so this has no affect at all in terms of disabling events.  Cancelling the default action for an event is NOT the same thing as disabling events.  It's just not.  If you attached this listener first, or attached it with a higher priority than all other events, then you could call stopImmediatePropagation, but preventDefault is useless for this problem.

Comment: Using `.on("click keypress")` should block both keyboard and mouse, and it's shorter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) jquery function for that.

```
$('#foo').unbind();
```

or if you want to disable specific events you can use it like:

```
 $('#foo').unbind('click');
```

Also, you could take a look at jquery's event namespacing. I think that is probably going to be useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

I´m using this for completely disable click for all the window.
Is a transparent overlay panel with a high z-Index, with this you can´t click anywhere.

```
var $ventanaModal = $('<div id="pantallaTransparente" class="ip-container containerFondoModal zIndexAlto"></div>');

$('body').prepend($ventanaModal);
```

And here is the css class:

```
.pantallaTransparente {
background: transparent;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 99999999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can bind a handler on the element that executes `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`

As long as this event fires first, all others will not fire.

Unfortunately, it is [not possible](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/event-priority) to manually define event priority. 
You have to make sure that the event is defined last in the stack.

Comment: Event priority exists in ActionScript 3, which blows JavaScript away, and has existed for a decade.  AS3's InteractiveObject.mouseEnabled property works like pointer-events:none, but actually disables all interaction events from both mouse and keyboard.  The inability to disable keyboard events or set event priority in 2017 is a huge failure of JavaScript.  Anyway, stopImmediatePropagation is the only correct answer to actually preventing keyboard events from firing.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener()

Answer (score 1):

Here is another old trick.

To avoid any contact with the mouse on your div, place another div of the same size on top (with z-index) of it with an opacity of 0 (or [equivalent for older browser](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/)).

You trigger it by changing the display property from none (default) to block.
When the div has a display set to block it will be on top of your regular div and make a wall between the mouse and your div.

It might not fit with your specific page and css architecture but if it does, it's easy to setup. :)

Comment: This won't prevent keyboard interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Can be solved by CSS. Use the below code

```
.div-element {
   pointer-events: none; // disable all the pointer events in div
}
.div-element * {
   pointer-events: auto; // enables all the pointer events in children elements of the div
}
```

Comment: It does not disable key events.

Comment: What about the Keyboard events?

Answer (score 0):

This worked as I expected:

```
element.style {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This will not disable keyboard events.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my used solution, which is automatically catching all readonly marked inputs via jQuery for click and keypress events - quite easy and simple fix, to make them really READONLY.

Nothing more to think about, just mark desired inputs as readonly and your are done.

```
 // prevent click and keypress events for readonly marked inputs
$(":input[readonly='readonly']").on("click keypress", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

*Possibly a little flickering during the click and keypress events is visible with Bootstrap. ;)*